# Uniqueness of solution of linear PDE of first order

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde

Let $\vec u\colon \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^k$
be at least $C^1$- smooth vector valued function. Assume they satisfy a first order linear equation
$$\partial_t \vec u(x,t)=\sum_{j=1}^n A_j(x,t) \partial_{x_j}\vec u(x,t),$$
where $A_j$ are matrix valued functions.

Assume in addition 
$$u(x,0)=0.$$

> Under what assumptions on the regularity of $\vec u, A_j$ (weaker than real analiticity, say infinite smoothness) one can guarantee that $u$ vanishes identically?

A reference would be helpful.

Comment: If your system is hyperbolic (in any of the usual senses), then you need almost no regularity assumptions on $A_j$ ($C^1$ is definitely enough, and you can possibly get away with less).